# Silverstripe: Page Controller Redirect Back not working

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a controller (PromoCode_Controller) which is an extension of Page_Controller. When I fire an action, I'd like the page to redirect back to the page it came from. I currently have `$this->redirectBack()` set up, but it's not firing...

I have the Page_Controller defined in my 'config.yml' file:

```
Page_Controller:
  extensions:
    - PromoCode_Controller
```

The controller looks as such:

```
<?php

class PromoCode_Controller extends Extension {
    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'DisplayCodes',
        'DeleteCode'
    );

    public function DisplayCodes() {
        //Display users promo codes
        $arrayList = ArrayList::create();
        $codes = PromoCode::get()->filter(array(
            "OwnerID" => Member::currentUserID(),
        ));

        foreach($codes as $code) {
            $arrayList->push($code);
        }
        return $arrayList;

    }

    public function DeleteCode() {
        $codeID = $this->owner->request->param("ID");
        //if($codeID && $code = PromoCode::get()->byID($codeID)) {
        //  $code->delete();
        //}
        echo $codeID;
        $this->redirectBack();
        return $this;
    }

}
```

I have a link in my template to delete the code from the DB. When I click the link, it prints the $codeID variable on a blank white page, but it doesn't fire the redirect.

Can someone help point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Probably the `echo $codeID;` preventing your redirect. As headers are already sent.

Comment: @Darren thanks for the reply. Just removed it there and still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to stumble upon the fix by accident. Here is the complete code:

```
public function DeleteCode() {
        $codeID = $this->owner->request->param("ID");
        if($codeID && $code = PromoCode::get()->byID($codeID)) {
            $code->delete();
        }

        return $this->owner->redirectBack();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to return the response from `redirectBack`. You can't do `redirectBack` and then return something else as you've done in your question.